# [pygame error message]type object 'sprite' has no attribute 'sprites'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and decided to implement some sprites into my game rather than just moving around objects. I want to get it so I increase the score every time the player runs into an obstacle, however I'm having a lot of trouble with the collide method.  However I keep receiving this error whenever I run the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rungameforryan.py", line 214, in <module>
blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, sprite.sprites, True)
AttributeError: type object 'sprite' has no attribute 'sprites'
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated. 
here is the game loop :

```
from classyforryan import ourMusic, sprites
import pygame
import os
import time

pygame.init() #short for initialize does return a tuple of successful intilizaton
colors={"black":(0,0,0), "white": (255, 255, 255), "red": (255, 0, 0), "green": (0, 255, 0), "purple": (164, 66, 244), "pink" :(252, 25, 123)}
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

bg=pygame.image.load('clouds_converted.jpg')
moore=pygame.image.load("baemoore_converted.png")
jump = False
fall = False

cube = pygame.image.load("cube.png")
player=sprites(moore, 50, 544)
ob = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob1 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)
ob2 = sprites(cube, 2125, 580)


pygame.display.set_caption("lets play!")
gameExit = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ob, ob1, ob2, image, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("1136693.jpg") #edited to add self. :)
        self.spritesgroup = pygame.sprite.Group() #sprite group
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob1)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob2)


while not gameExit:
    clock.tick(40)
    timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    print(timer)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit=True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                gameExit= True
    pygame.display.update()
    gameDisplay.blit(bg,[0,0])
    time.sleep(.05)
    player.pos()
    ob.pos()
    ob.left()
    ob1.pos()
    ob2.pos()

blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, sprite.spritesgroup, True)
    for block in blocks_hit_list:
        score +=1
    print(score)
pygame.quit() #unintiliazes pygames
quit() #this will exit out of python
```

and here are all the classes that were imported :

```
import pygame
import os
import time
gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

class sprites(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, xcoor, ycoor):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rectx=xcoor
        self.recty=ycoor
    def pos(self):
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, [self.rectx, self.recty])
    def left(self):
        dist = 7
        self.rectx = self.rectx - dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) for `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` say that parameter should be a group of sprites.  It looks like you created a class, `sprite` that was meant to hold that group, but you assigned the group to local variables instead of instance members.  I added a `self.` to those, and changed the line you were getting errors on so that it referenced it.  I'm guessing that's what you wanted, but can't really tell for sure.

```
class sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ob, ob1, ob2, image, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.spritesgroup = pygame.sprite.Group() #sprite group
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob1)
        self.spritesgroup.add(ob2)
        #sprites.add(player)

# ...            

sprite1 = sprite(ob, ob1, ob2, "1136693.jpg", "location")
blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, sprite1.spritesgroup, True)
```

Comment: Hi so I tried this but I'm still getting the same error even when I added the self.  .. Do I need to be calling the class somewhere else in the program?

Comment: @S.Mahmud:  Sorry, I could have swore you instantiated an instance of your class.  I'll tweak my answer a bit.

Comment: ok, so I fixed it so that it doesn't give me the error anymore but now it won't pick up any of the obstacles hit.. //I'm looking at my code now for a further explanation on how I fixed that// also I just added the self. after see your suggestions so no worries